# SharePoint search field

Tags: sharepoint

there's a small issue.

The folders aren't being found when moving a file in SharePoint. This problem isn't limited to just moving a file; it also occurs when searching for folders using the search field.

It's definitely not due to incorrect folders destination , refreshing the SharePoint page, or the folders being archived. it's also not about permissions.

Comment: This is specifically a Sharepoint question, perhaps better asked at [Sharepoint SE](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/)